# Why docker showing localhost data?

Tags: docker

I have installed Docker and Apache 2.

The network address of docker is `172.17.0.1` and when i hit it at URL in browser why it is showing the data of `127.0.0.1` (localhost).

Docker has its own network it should show the data of its network.

```
aman@aman-pc ~ $ ifconfig
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:f1:d4:a4:20  
          inet addr:**172.17.0.1**  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:f1ff:fed4:a420/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:17823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24448 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1040754 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:36481470 (36.4 MB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:f7:28:39:e7:69  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:**127.0.0.1**  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:21029 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21029 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2776697 (2.7 MB)  TX bytes:2776697 (2.7 MB)
```

Comment: Are you accessing the container using its ip address or via a port exposed with `-p`?

Comment: Could you provide the docker run command please? Are you accessing the container from a web browser dockerized on the same LAN? Using the exposed port?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you did and the steps to reproduce this? It sounds like you installed Apache httpd on the *host* machine? Or are you talking about running Apache httpd as a Docker container? Please provide some steps to reproduce.

Comment: I ran container with a image of ubuntu and apache. after that when i enter 172.17.0.1 (Network of docker), it is showing the content of my local host (127.0.0.1) www dir. Doesn't it supposed to  show its internal www dir content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found out the solution

Lets start with the **ip address**, It provides the address of the host, when you hit the url it send the request to the host. Now when the request comes to host, the host analyse the request and checks its port. So whenever you hit a url, without specifying its port, it send request with port 80(default for http). Now the host has server(apache2) installed, by this the host is configured to any request that comes with **port 80**, will be handled by apache2.

Now regarding above problem, Your system have apache2, docker, localhost etc. installed. So when you hit url (`172.17.0.1`) it sends the request to the host(right now your system is the host). Now when your system receive the request, it checks its port i.e. 80. Now it will check that which application is running on port 80 (apache2) and send request to apache2. After that apache2 handles request and send its localhost data, because it is configured to localhost(`127.0.0.1`).

So if you want request to handle by docker's apache2, then you should map the port 80 with another new port and hit the url [`172.17.0.1:(new port no.)`]. It will redirect to docker's apache2.

> For more information on mapping https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/